# How I can combine two query that will count rows?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How can I combine this two query into one thank you in advance.

```php
$mayorcountqry = $conn->prepare("SELECT VOTE_STATUS FROM voters where VOTE_STATUS = ? AND prcnt_no = ? ");
$mayorcountqry->execute([$MAYOR,$prcnt_no]);
$countmayor = $mayorcountqry->rowCount();   
                                        
$triocountqry = $conn->prepare("SELECT VOTE_STATUS FROM voters where VOTE_STATUS = ? AND prcnt_no = ? ");
$triocountqry->execute([$TRIO,$prcnt_no]);
$triocount= $triocountqry->rowCount();
```

Comment: You can use the `IN` operator. Syntax: `WHERE [columnName] IN (?, ?)`.

Comment: how can i call each count?

Comment: You use the aggregate function `COUNT(*)`

Comment: i tried this SELECT VOTE_STATUS FROM voters where VOTE_STATUS IN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters where VOTE_STATUS =?  ) and  VOTE_STATUS IN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters where VOTE_STATUS =?

Comment: can i know the correct syntax for this thank you

Comment: Your queries are not counting, which makes your question really confusing.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SQL Union?

Syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

You can then just count for each.

Comment: i already solved it using sum(case when VOTE_STATUS = ?  then 1 else 0 end) AS countmayor,